# Passing return value of method as parameter to another method in same class

Tags: java

Is it possible to use return value(i) from find method as the parameter of isSubstringAt as(index)?

if not possible :

how can I assign (index) value to (i) value in isSubstringAt Method?

Thanks in advance!

```
class Finder {

    public int find(String orginalString, String subString) {

        int m = subString.length();
        int n = orginalString.length();

        for (int i = 0; i <= n - m; i++) {
            int j;

            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (orginalString.charAt(i + j) != subString.charAt(j)) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (j == m) {

                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }


    public boolean isSubstringAt(String originalString, String substring, int index) {


        if (index + substring.length() > originalString.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < substring.length(); j++) {
            if (originalString.charAt(index + j) != substring.charAt(j)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried `isSubstringAt(original, sub , find(original,sub));` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you call find, assign the value to a variable and pass it into the next method:

```
int index = find(original, sub);

boolean isSub = isSubstringAt(original, sub, index);
```

is this the desired result?

> this can be done on one line but using variables for easy reading

Comment: @MohrezaKh you can do it in one line using this `boolean isSub = isSubstringAt(original, sub, find(original, sub));`